# Why do we use Adar, specifically, for the Jewish leap year?

Tags: calendar, rosh-chodesh-new-month, adar

Why when we add an additional month to the year do we only add it in Adar? Why not have a second Cheshvon or a second Shevat, etc.?

Comment: Nisan is the beginning of months (Exodus 12:2), making Adar the last, and Tishri the seventh (Leviticus 23:24, 29:1). Compare this to the case of the Julian and Gregorian calendars, adding an extra day at the end of February, since the ancient Roman calendar, whose descendants they are, also had its original first month, March, in spring.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We add the additional month in order to keep Pesach in the spring, as the Torah mandates ([Deut. 16:1](http://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.16.1?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all)). So it is added as close to Nissan as possible, in order to make explicit the link between the extra month and its purpose.

---

Tosafos ([Sanhedrin 11b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=11b&format=pdf), s.v. [אין מעברין](http://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Sanhedrin.11b.35?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all)) says that since we have verses in Tanach ([Esther 3:7](http://www.sefaria.org/Esther.3.7?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all) passim) that call Adar the "twelfth month," then necessarily no other month can be inserted before it, otherwise some years it would be the thirteenth.

The Mechilta ([Bo 2](http://www.sefaria.org/Mekhilta.12.2.6?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all)) cites a different reason: the year should be similar to the month in the way it's extended - in both cases, the extension (a day or a month) comes at the end.

Comment: Adding a month to Shevat would accomplish that too?

Comment: But then the linkage with שמור את חודש האביב wouldn't be as clear.

Comment: That is great!!

Comment: If this is so, then why do we add the it before the regular Adar? _Adar Bet_, like the one in regular years, is 29 days long, and Purim falls in it. _Adar Alef_ is 30 days long. I'd conclude from that, that _Adar Alef_ is the added one.

Answer (score 8):

[Sanhedrin 11b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=11b&format=pdf):  Before the setting of the calendar, those in charge of being meaber would base their decision on two of three factors which were related to the ripeness of the produce during adar (is the barley ripe enough to call Nissan "Aviv", will the fruits be ripe for Shavuos), and could not be determined earlier.

Answer (score 5):

The pamphlet "הדף היומי בהלכה", published by Dirshu, issue 4, Ⅰ *Adar* 5774, cites [*K'dushas Levi* (*Ki Sisa*)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50006&pgnum=115) and *S'fas Emes* (*likutim* for *Adar*) as saying that the month of *Adar* (whose zodiac sign is fish) corresponds to *Yosef* (which, like fish, is unaffected by *ayin hara*) — see the *Tur* ([*OC* 417](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1926)), who says each month corresponds to a tribe. Thus, it had to be the month to split into two, since *Yosef* is the tribe that split into two, *M'nashe* and *Efrayim*.

Answer (score 3):

Adar is the last month in the year. So from a simple technical standpoint it's the easiest to add a month then. Especially if you want all the other months' numbers to remain like they should be (and more importantly - compatible with what the Torah calls them)