# Why are the rules for parsha "catch up" different for leap vs. non-leap years?

Tags: calendar, torah-reading

When Pesach is on Shabbat, as it is this year and next, the Torah reading in Diaspora is a week behind the reading in Israel for a few weeks. This is because on the 8th day of Pesach which is on Shabbat in Diaspora, they read a holiday reading, while in Israel, since it is no longer Pesach, they are reading the regular Shabbat parsha.

During a non-leap year, the "catch up" parsha for Diaspora is *Behar-B'chukotai*. In Diaspora it is read doubled, whereas in Israel, they are read separately.

However, in a leap year, the catch up parsha is *Matot-Mas'ei* - almost 2 months later.  In Diaspora, they are read together, but in Israel, they are read separately.

Why is there a difference?

To help you understand when this occurs and gain some insight, perhaps, see pp. 67 and 70 (Tables 1 and 2) in [this article](http://www.hakirah.org/vol%202%20epstein.pdf). I couldn't find anything that addresses this difference, though, it may, in fact be there, but I missed it.

Comment: In a leap year Behar Bechukotai is already set to be split. See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15600/759 (possible dupe?)

Comment: @DoubleAA - Well, even though I answered my own question, it does look like a dupe. We just explained the reason differently, and I included some extra info from Ramba"m. Is there a way to combine the answers, or should I copy mine to there?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, in fact, I **did** miss a nuance mentioned on p. 71 of the article that I linked to in the question.

> The only requirement in the Gemara concerning Shabbos Torah readings
>   is limited to the need to read certain portions of the Torah prior to
>   Shevuos and Rosh Hashanah, :מגילה לא׃ תניא ר׳ שמעון בן אלעזר אומר עזרא
>   תיקן להן לישראל שיהו קורין קללות שבתורת כהנים קודם עצרת ושבמשנה תורה
>   קודם ראש השנה

The rule states that the "curses" located in *Bechukotai* should be read before *Shavuot*. It is unclear if this means immediately before Shavu'ot, or by the time Shavu'ot comes, it should have already been read, meaning that it can be read 1 0r 2 weeks earlier.

> Rambam תפילה יג׃ב after quoting the above Gemara almost verbatim,7
>   adds:
>
> ...והמנהג הפשוט שיהו קוראין במדבר סיני קודם עצרת. ואתחנן אחר תשעה באב.
>   אתם נצבים קודם ראש השנה. וצו את אהרן קודם הפסח בשנה פשוטה. לפיכך יש
>   שבתות שקורין בשחרית שני סדרין כגון אשה כי תזריע וזאת תהיה.ובהר סיני
>   ואם בחוקותי וכיוצא בהן כדי שישלימו בשנה ויקראו אותן הסדרים בעונתן

So it seems, that Ramba"m insists that we leave 1 week between *Bechukotai* and Shavu'ot. It seems that this is the opinion that we follow.

I checked the calendar arrangement in MS Outlook comparing this year with next year, as Pesach is on Shabbat in both years - this year regular year and next year a leap year.

This year, a non-leap year, if we (Diaspora) didn't double them up, *Bechukotai* would be read on Erev Shavu'ot, which is the Shabbat immediately prior to Shavu'ot (Shavu'ot is on Sunday.) Therefore, this parsha is doubled.

Next year, which is a leap year, in Diaspora, Bechukotai which is read on its own is already 2 weeks before Shavu'ot, and the Shabbat immediately before Shavu'ot is *Bamidbar*.

Ramba"m mentions an additional concern, namely that *Va'etchanan* be read after Tish'a B'Av. To do this, *Devarim* must be the parsha immediately before (or on) Tish'a B'av (as is this year. I think that's why Ramba"m was careful to phrase things in terms of *Va'etchanan*.) To do this, in Israel, *Matot-Mas'ei* are read separately. (In most years, they are doubled.)

Comment: Note sometimes Naso is read prior to Shavuot.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Correct- in Diaspora it always occurs in a leap year when Rosh Hashanna is on Thurs. In Israel, I think there are 2 other times when this happens. I think next year, would be such an occurrence. This explains why Matot and Mas'ei would be read separately, to "slow down" the pace.

Comment: B'Chukotai must be at least 2 Shabbatot before Shavuot, not immediately the one before. Israel though could achieve it this year by splitting Tazria-Metzora or Acharei-Kedoshim, either of which would let the Haftara from Amos to be read which it won't be this year